# trying to remove certain characters from inside of double quotes but leave them intact as delimiters

Tags: bash, sed, awk

remove characters(semicolons) from inside of quoted string but keep them intact for delimiters

How do I get sed etc. to do this.

My input file

```
"1234";"ABCDE;";"9999"
"2344;";"PQRST"; "3456;"
```

My outpuft file needs to be cleaned up to look like

```
"1234";"ABCDE";"9999"
"2344";"PQRST";"3456"
```

As seen above the semicolons need to be retained as delimiters but need to be removed from the quoted parts. Would anyone be able to let me know? Thanks.

I am actually doing some hive programming and my hive scripts are ready and running successfully (as tested on smaller sample data sets). Now those same scripts are giving me errors since these new big data sets are not clean and hence trying to clean them up (& learning sed etc. along the way).

regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 3):

**I think you would be better off with a CSV parser.**

If you have `gawk`, you can use the [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) variable. Try:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { FPAT="([^; ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS=";" } { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/;/, "", $i) }1' file
```

Results:

```
"1234";"ABCDE";"9999"
"2344";"PQRST";"3456"
```

---

If, for whatever reason you cannot easily upgrade your distro, here's a solution using [Perl](http://www.perl.org) and the [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org) module [Text:CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm):

```
perl -MText::CSV -nle '
    BEGIN { $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ";", allow_whitespace => 1 }) }
    $csv->parse($_) or die;
    print join(";", map { s/;//g; s/^|$/"/g; $_ } $csv->fields())
' file
```

Results:

```
"1234";"ABCDE";"9999"
"2344";"PQRST";"3456"
```

Comment: Its important to note that `FPAT` is within `gawk` 4.xx and many distro still does not have this version.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you don't have record like this:

```
";";";";";"
```

You can break your task into these steps:

#### `cat input`

```
"1234";"ABCDE;";"9999"
"2344;";"PQRST"; "3456;"
```

#### `sed -r 's@"\s*;\s*"@|@g'`

```
"1234|ABCDE;|9999"
"2344;|PQRST|3456;"
```

#### `sed -r 's@[";]@@g'`

```
1234|ABCDE|9999
2344|PQRST|3456
```

#### `sed -r 's@[^|]+@"&"@g'`

```
"1234"|"ABCDE"|"9999"
"2344"|"PQRST"|"3456"
```

#### `sed -r 's@\|@;@g'`

```
"1234";"ABCDE";"9999"
"2344";"PQRST";"3456"
```

---

Put all commands into one:

```
sed -r 's@"\s*;\s*"@|@g;s@[";]@@g;s@[^|]+@"&"@g;s@\|@;@g' input
```

Answer (score 2):

**sed**

```
kent$  sed -r 's/;"(;"|$)/"\1/g' f 
"1234";"ABCDE";"9999"
"2344";"PQRST"; "3456"
```

**awk**

one-liner: longer version:

```
kent$  awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/\S+;$/){sub(/;$/,"",$i)}}7' f   
"1234";"ABCDE";"9999"
"2344";"PQRST"; "3456"
```

oner-liner shorter but with trash(`"`) in last line:

```
kent$  awk -v RS='"' -v ORS='"' '/\S+;$/{sub(/;$/,"")}7' f    
"1234";"ABCDE";"9999"
"2344";"PQRST"; "3456"
"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '
    {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i=="\"") f=!f
        if ($i==";" && f) $i=x
        printf $i}
    } {print ""}
    ' FS="" file
"1234";"ABCDE";"9999"
"2344";"PQRST"; "3456"
```

This test if `;` is within a block of two `"`, if yes, remove it.

---

To also remove space between fields, use this:

```
awk '
    {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i=="\"") f=!f
        if ($i==";" && f) $i=x
        if ($i==" " && !f) $i=x
        printf $i}
    } {print ""}
    ' FS="" file
```